# Chrome WebRTC: Why can't I send 1080p video?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

In Google Chrome 33, I can record and render local video at 1080p but when I stream it to the remote end it always ends up getting received as 720p. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Google Chrome. Please vote for https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259440

Comment: Update: Issue has been fixed.